# How to calculate this surface integral with ImplicitRegion and RegionBoundary?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I calculate this surface integral with ImplicitRegion and RegionBoundary?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg1 = Region[
   ImplicitRegion[
    x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && x + y + z < 1, {x, y, z}]];
reg2 = RegionBoundary[reg1];
f[x_, y_, z_] := x*y*z;
Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg2]]

(* Returns unevaluated *)
```

Comment: `NIntegrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg2]]` evaluates!

Comment: `reg2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg1]` and `Integrate[f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, reg2]]`

Comment: @Syed What's  your Mathematica version? v12.2 doesn't evaluate your code.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRiyy.png).

Comment: @Syed With freh kernel code runs, thanks!

Comment: The results are different, though. (0.0144338 vs  0.00138889). Not sure what to make of the results.

Comment: @Syed: I think the discretization makes the difference. Try something like  `MaxCellMeasure -> .1`.

Comment: @user64494, no change even for `MaxCellMeasure->0.01`. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @Syed:`reg3 = DiscretizeRegion[reg2] ; Integrate[x*y*z, 
 Element[{x, y, z}, reg3]]` performs `0.0144338`.

Comment: Thanks, @user64494, it does.

Comment: Thanks for comments!

Answer (score 2):

One way is as directed in the Ulrich Neumann's comment.

```
Clear["Global`*"];reg1 = Region[ImplicitRegion[
x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && x + y + z <= 1, {x, y, z}]];reg2 = RegionBoundary[reg1];
NIntegrate[x*y*z, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg2]
```

> `0.01443375672974058`

```
RootApproximant[%]
```

> `1/(40 Sqrt[3])`

The command of Maple

```
VectorCalculus:-SurfaceInt(x*y*z, [x, y, z] = Surface(<s, t, 1 - s - t>, [s, t] = Triangle(<0, 0>, <1, 0>, <0, 1>)))
```

> `sqrt(3)/120`

confirms it (The integrals over the triangles  lying in the coordinate planes equal  zero.).

Comment: I'd like to add that Mathematica is able to calculate this surface integral, making use of `Integrate[x*y*(1 - x - y)*Sqrt[1 + D[1 - x - y, x]^2 + 
         D[1 - x - y, y]^2], Element[{x, y}, 
     Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]]` which results in `1/(40 Sqrt[3])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @user64494

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a piece-wise surface,we need to calculate all the individual surface integral and sum up.

```
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
triangles = Triangle /@ Subsets[pts, {3}];
Integrate[x*y*z, {x, y, z} ∈ #] & /@ triangles // Total
```

> `1/(40 Sqrt[3])`

Comment: How do you derive `pts` from `reg2`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! @cvgmt